# Custom module collection array not return

Tags: collection, magento2.3.2, array, returns

I have created a custom module and I have return collection array but it does not return foreach array in Magento 2.3.2. it returns the only foreach last value.

**Block Code**

```
<?php
namespace Developer\Infographics\Block\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;


class Leftinfographics extends Template {

    public function __construct(
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,

        array $data = []) 
    {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getCategoryViceversaCollection()
    {
        $collection = array();
        $finalsearch = 'test,magento,abc,xyz'
        $commaList = explode(',', $finalsearch);
        foreach ($commaList as $key => $value) {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('tags', array('like' => '%'.$value.'%'));
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Template Code**

```
$productxyzdata = $block->getXYZ();
var_dump($productCollectiondata->getData());
```

Comment: this is because you are creating a new collection with every iteration, thus only having the last one

Comment: expose your complete code if possible @Devidas

Comment: yes sure........!

Comment: Upload your full code please.

Comment: check I have update code @RohanHapani

Comment: Replace your collectionFactory's construct class please which I mentioned and update code. Then remove generated and clean cache.

Comment: I have replace collection factory then show error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Nuucleon\Infographics\Model\ResourceModel\Infographics\Collection::getCollection()

Comment: @RohanHapani my custom module collection data load using \Developer\Infographics\Model\InfographicsFactory only issue is in foreach only last value return array collection

Comment: Yes. I know. But, did you tried my solution. Which way I told you?

Comment: I tried your solution @RohanHapani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100740/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-devidas).

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are creating a new collection with every iteration, thus only having the last one

```
$collection = array();
$finalsearch = 'test,magento,abc,xyz'
$commaList = explode(',', $finalsearch);
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
foreach ($commaList as $key => $value) {
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('tags', array('like' => '%'.$value.'%'));
}
return $collection;
```

Comment: error invalid method Developer\Infographics\Model\Infographics::addFieldToFilter

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way

```
$collection = [];
$finalsearch = 'test,magento,abc,xyz';
$commaList = explode(',', $finalsearch);
foreach ($commaList as $key => $value) {
    $collection[] = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('tags', array('like' => '%'.$value.'%'));
}
return $collection;
```

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: What does error occur if you use this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code :

```
$collection = [];
$finalsearch = 'test,magento,abc,xyz';
$commaList = explode(',', $finalsearch);
foreach ($commaList as $key => $value) {
    $collection[] = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('tags', ['like' => '%' . $value . '%'])->getData();
}
return $collection;
```

make sure your collection class should be `Developer\Infographics\Model\ResourceModel\Infographics\CollectionFactory`

Comment: same error invalid method Developer\Infographics\Model\Infographics::addFieldToFilter